# pyshp not working properly when creating polygons (offset + missing polygons)

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, pyshp

I have a Esri shapefile thats projected in NSIDC EASE-Grid Global that has roughly 50k polygons. I wrote the Python script below to create a grid that covers the span of each polygons bbox (note I don't care if there are rectangles that don't intersect a polygon because I am going to use QGIS to remove any that don't; my computer just doesn't have enough memory/disc space to create a grid that covers the extent of the whole world).

However, my code seems to have an offset i.e all the rectangles are off by a constant amount from where they should be. Furthermore, the script just doesn't create a grid of rectangles for some polygons in the shapefile?! I have checked the validity of all the polygons and they all check out. I'm not sure what's going wrong... how can I figure this out?

```
import shapefile
import math
import time
sf = shapefile.Reader("2500_mines_NSDIC_EASE/2500_mines_NSDIC_EASE.shp")

shapes = sf.shapes()
w = shapefile.Writer('grid/grid', shapeType=shapefile.POLYGON)
w.field('name', 'C')
count = 1
start = time.time()
def create_poly(bottom_x, bottom_y, width, height):
    global count
    w.poly([[[bottom_x, bottom_y],[bottom_x+width, bottom_y], [bottom_x+width, bottom_y+height], [bottom_x, bottom_y+height], [bottom_x, bottom_y]]])
    w.record('rect' + str(count))
    count += 1
tile_size = 400#pixels
resolution = 10 #m/pixel
rect_dim = tile_size * resolution
num_processed = 0
for shape in shapes:
    bbox = shape.bbox
    minx = bbox[0]
    miny = bbox[1]
    maxx = bbox[2]
    maxy = bbox[3]
    assert(minx < maxx)
    assert(miny < maxy)

    minx_tile = math.floor(minx/rect_dim) -1
    miny_tile = math.floor(miny/rect_dim) -1
    maxx_tile = math.ceil(maxx/rect_dim) + 1
    maxy_tile = math.ceil(maxy/rect_dim) + 1

    for x in range(minx_tile, maxx_tile+1):##inclusive, exclusive
        for y in range(miny_tile, maxy_tile+1):
            create_poly(x*rect_dim, y*rect_dim, rect_dim, rect_dim)
    num_processed += 1
    if (num_processed % 1000 == 0):
        print("Processed " + str(num_processed) + " mines. " + str(count) + " polygons " + str(time.time()-start))
        

w.close()
```

Heres an example of the offset (the other rectangles for other polygons are offset by the same ammount)(viewed in QGIS)
[image: example 1]

For some reason there appears to be no overlap in Northern Africa?
[image: example 2]

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77774290/pyshp-not-working-properly-when-creating-polygons-offset-missing-polygons

Comment: I know I posted it on gis and stack overflow b/c i wasn't sure which category it would fall under